# react router v4 does not render any other route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement react router but having few problems. Please find the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App, Home, Signup } from './containers';
import routes from './routes';
import { BrowserRouter , Route } from 'react-router-dom'


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The App.js file which I am using as a Layout is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Cheader } from '../components';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Cheader/>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

It works when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/, but it does not work when i try to navigate to http://localhost:3000/signup. The page displays the following error:

```
Cannot GET /signup
```

The code for signup components and containers is as below:
components: index.js, signuppage.js

```
import Cheader from './cheader';
import Signuppage from './signuppage';
import Homepage from './homepage';

export {
  Cheader,
  Homepage,
  Signuppage
}

import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Signuppage = () => (
  <Grid>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        This is test
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
);

export default Signuppage;
```

containers: index.js, Signup.js

```
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home';
import Signup from './Signup';

export {
  App,
  Home,
  Signup
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Signuppage } from '../components';

class Signup extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Signuppage/>
    )
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

It seems to be working for the default path, but not for any other route. am I missing any configuration here. Please note that I am using react-router v4. Can anyone please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share containers.js? Looks like there is problem with your Signup .

Comment: Hi Win, I have added code for Signup containers and components. Signup container is using the Signuppage component.

Answer (score 1):

It is expalined in this: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

When you try to go to the link directly, your server cannot find a file match to signup.

Solution 1: Use HashRouter to replace BrowserRouter.

Solution 2: Use fallback technique to setup server that fall back to '/' when no file matched is found.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `exact` to the first route

```
<App>
   <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
   <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
</App>
```

another thing can be that you missing pushState settings in your dev server configuration

if you use webpack, add:

```
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Comment: Hi Kejt, I tried adding that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: quick fix would be to move your signup route component above root route, but have you tried to switch containers and show signup component on `/` path?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both the ways, but it doesnt work. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: and what about signup component on the '/' path, is it working?

Comment: another thing is that maybe your server doesnt support pushState, do you use webpack?